# Algebra of error models and error correcting codes?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, error-correcting-codes, entropy, algebra

In coding theory we typically consider the situation where we have a
channel that connects a sender and receiver. The messages flowing from
the sender to the receiver are corrupted by an error source ES. We
have an error detection and correction mechanism that is typically
fine-tuned to ES. Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_theory) uses this image:

[image: Channel model]

But what if we have more than one error source, say $ES1$ and $ES2$. We
can have a error detection and correction mechanism for each but they
can then be combined in different ways. Moreover, even if the error
detection and correction mechanism for $ES1$ is fine-tuned to $ES1$, and
likewise for $ES2$, it is not a priori clear that any combined error
detection and correction mechanism has the required properties for the
combined error model.  So we can imagine an algebra of error sources
and error detection and correction mechanisms. I'm sure this has been
investigated before.

Where can I find related work in this direction?

Comment: Where did you see that the error control is fine-tuned to the error source ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust For example in micro-processors and dRAMs, where the additional costs of error correction (transistors cost power and "area") weighted against their benefits. Another example is mobile phone data transmission. Complex error correction schemes cost a lot of compute which increases compute, hence energy consumption, which mobile phones are sensitive to.

Comment: Any reference about "fine-tuning" of error codes in these contexts ? (I mean specifically, not about general usage of error control codes.)

Comment: Not to the top of my head, I'd have to dig through papers. But Shannon's original work on channel capacity tunes the codes that achieve the Shannon limit to the distribution of the noise source.

Comment: For example the Wikipedia entries https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECC_memory and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory both state this. It's kind of obvious that, e.g., you dont need a (7,19)-Hamming code if your error model says at most one bit gets flipped.